# jQuery .toggle requires double click to open when interupted by .click

Tags: jquery, click, toggle, double-click

I am having a problem with my toggle function. I have a simple div that moves up and down when clicked using the `.toggle`. To make the page easier etc to use I want the user to be able to click anywhere on the screen in order to 'close' move the div back down without having to click on the blue box again (sort of like on a mega drop down menu).

Problem is my `.click` function messes up the toggle and once the blue div is closed by the `.click` rather than the second function of the `.toggle`, the `.toggle` then needs to be clicked twice in order for it to be opened again. What am I doing wrong?

I have searched other related problems with `.toggle` and double clicks on here but with no luck in finding a similar topic

I have tried some `.addClass` and `.hasClass` stuff but it doesn't seem to be working.

Also here is my jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){


$(document).click(function() {
            if($("#banner").hasClass("open")){
                    $("#banner").removeClass("open").stop().animate({top:"350px"},350, 'swing')
            }});


$("#banner").toggle(
        function () {
            $(this).addClass("open").animate({top:"200px"},350, 'swing')
            },
        function () {
            $(this).removeClass("open").animate({top:"350px"},350, 'swing')
            });

});
```

Comment: When asking questions, please try to illustrate the problem in the question itself. Links to show the problem are subject to two issues: (1) they often will no longer show the problem once it is fixed, and (2) they often die or expire. If you can show the issue in a Snippet or a Fiddle, that is much more permanent `:-)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just change `toggle` to `click`:

```
$("#banner").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($("#banner").hasClass("open")) {
        $("#banner").removeClass("open").animate({
            top: "350px"
        }, 350, 'swing')
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass("open").animate({
            top: "200px"
        }, 350, 'swing');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey Kei, Thanks for the reply. Didn't think of doing it that way. Thanks a lot.